# iFrame alternative for getting cross-domain URL

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm creating a web-based game. As a part of it, the player must go to the home page of a website, and follow a series of link until he reaches to the "destination page" in the minor time possible. Think of it as a sort of link treasure hunt.

In order to control the game, I created a page with a javascript timer on the top, and an iFrame showing the website to surf (which is not mine and I have no control over it).

However this has a huge fault: it is not possible to detect the current cross-domain URL of the iFrame, so my page cannot know when the user has arrived to the destination page and stop the game.

Is there any alternative way I could achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any alternative way I could achieve this?

No, there is not.

The Same Origin Policy *completely* prevents you from accessing properties of any window object that displays content from another domain.

(If one was a subdomain of the other, then `document.domain` would help. But from your problem description it doesn’t sound like that was the case.)

---

And besides the technical issue: Generating traffic and clicks (that will skew their statistics/analytics) on a site that you don’t own, just for the purpose of being able to present your own game, would be rather unfair (aka a “dick move”.)

Comment: The website owner has given me the permission to do so, I would never do this otherwise. However, clearly, he is not willing to edit his website in order to make it compatible with my game

Comment: Ah OK, in that case … :) They would not need to make any major modifications – if they were willing to embed an external JavaScript form your site, then you could use `postMessage` to communicate between the frames. (Koushik mentioned postMessage in his answer already, but I don’t think his approach would work – the “you can add a onload handler on iFrame's `<body>`” part is where the SOP would say nope again.)

Answer (score 0):

You can wait upto the `contentWindow` of the iFrame is resolved and you have a reference to the iFrame's window, after you changed the source pragmatically. 
once you have that, you can add a onload handler on iFrame's `<body>` and inject some `postMessage` call inside that handler, so once the body is loaded of the iFrame's window it wil call postMessage from the onload handler of body and it will notify your outer window, of-course you have to add message listener in outer window using `window.addEventListener("message", callback)`

Comment: This sounds interesting, but I guess it doesn't work for cross-domain iFrames, does it?

Comment: `postMessage` works across domain boundaries; but I doubt that the SOP allows this part: _“you can add a onload handler on iFrame's `<body>`”_

Comment: yes it will, for details see postMessage API, the purpose of the API tis to communicate with cross domain within different window of iframe's and main window.

Comment: @CBore though i am not sure it will to add a handler or not, but if you have a reference to the iframe's window you can do several operations. and in the case it dose't allow the provider of the website may need to add some little script that will call a postMessage to the window.parent (in the case window !== window.parent) o load complete or at any particular point as required.